# Possibility to simplify $\sum\limits_{k = - \infty }^\infty {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}} = \frac{\pi }{{\sin \pi a}}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, special-functions

Is there any way to show that

$$\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}} = \frac{1}{a} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\frac{1}{{a - k}} + \frac{1}{{a + k}}} \right)}=\frac{\pi }{{\sin \pi a}}} $$

Where $0 < a = \dfrac{n+1}{m} < 1$

The infinite series is equal to

$$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{at}}}}{{{e^t} + 1}}dt} $$

To get to the result, I split the integral at $x=0$ and use the convergent series in $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ respectively:

$$\frac{1}{{1 + {e^t}}} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{e^{ - \left( {k + 1} \right)t}}} $$

$$\frac{1}{{1 + {e^t}}} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{e^{kt}}} $$

Since $0 < a < 1$

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{{{e^{\left( {k + a} \right)t}}}}{{k + a}} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  - \infty } \frac{{{e^{\left( {k + a} \right)t}}}}{{k + a}} = \frac{1}{{k + a}}  \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty } \frac{{{e^{\left( {a - k - 1} \right)t}}}}{{k + a}} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{{{e^{\left( {a - k - 1} \right)t}}}}{{k + a}} =  - \frac{1}{{a - \left( {k + 1} \right)}} \cr} $$

A change in the indices will give the desired series.

Although I don't mind direct solutions from tables and other sources, I prefer an elaborated answer.

---

Here's the solution in terms of $\psi(x)$. By separating even and odd indices we can get

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a + 2k}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a + 2k + 1}}}   \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a - k}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a - 2k}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a - 2k - 1}}}  \cr} $$

which gives

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {\frac{{a + 1}}{2}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {\frac{a}{2}} \right)$$

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a - k}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {1 - \frac{a}{2}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {1 - \frac{{a + 1}}{2}} \right) + \frac{1}{a}$$

Then

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}}  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a - k}}}  - \frac{1}{a} =   \cr 
  &  = \left\{ {\frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {1 - \frac{a}{2}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {\frac{a}{2}} \right)} \right\} - \left\{ {\frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {1 - \frac{{a + 1}}{2}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {\frac{{a + 1}}{2}} \right)} \right\} \cr} $$

But using the reflection formula one has

$$\eqalign{
  & \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {1 - \frac{a}{2}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {\frac{a}{2}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}\cot \frac{{\pi a}}{2}  \cr 
  & \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {1 - \frac{{a + 1}}{2}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\psi \left( {\frac{{a + 1}}{2}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}\cot \frac{{\pi \left( {a + 1} \right)}}{2} =  - \frac{\pi }{2}\tan \frac{{\pi a}}{2} \cr} $$

So the series become

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}}  = \frac{\pi }{2}\left\{ {\cot \frac{{\pi a}}{2} + \tan \frac{{\pi a}}{2}} \right\}  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}}  = \pi \csc \pi a \cr} $$

The last being an application of a trigonometric identity.

Comment: It seems that using contour integration with the residue theorem should work here. Have you tried that?

Comment: @savick01 I know nothing about Complex Analisys. I'd prefer the use of the Digamma Function, which I'm familiar with.

Comment: I suppose you are interpreting that infinite sum as $\frac{1}{a} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k(\frac{1}{a+k} + \frac{1}{a-k})$.

Comment: @Aryabhata What do you mean?

Comment: @Peter: The order in which you combine them would matter I would think.

Comment: @Aryabhata I honestly can't understand you.

Comment: @Peter: Ok, different question: What is the $1000^{th}$ terms of the series you just gave?

Comment: @Aryabhata I know what you mean, but I think the notation is understandable and succint.

Comment: @Peter: No. Different mathematicians might have different interpretations. Why be ambiguous deliberately?

Comment: @Aryabhata I don't think its ambiguous. If you think it is, just edit it and let's move on.

Comment: @Peter: I don't care. I was only trying to help. If you don't want it, your problem.

Comment: @Aryabhata It's OK. Let's don't make this an argument. I accept your suggestion.

Comment: @Peter : Let's continue our discussion here : in what course did you encounter this question?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I was trying to solve $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^m}}}{{1 + {x^n}}}dx} $$ which led me to ($x^n = e^t$) $$\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{at}}}}{{1 + {e^t}}}dx} $$ which led me to $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}}} $$ ($a = \dfrac{m+1}{n}$)

Comment: I've had fun computing on wolfram alpha the pairs $(m,n) = (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)$ and it always diverges. $(1,3)$ converges to $\frac{2\pi}{ 3 \sqrt 3}$. Since $\frac{3 \sqrt 3}2 > 1$, I expect that something went wrong in your calculations that gave you $\pi/\sin(a\pi)$ since $\sin(ax)$ is never greater than $1$. But again, this is just calculations... maybe I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: But you turned it upside-down. $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}<1$

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Also note that I impose an important condition $n+1<m$ which is not satisfied by you values. (I edited to make it consistent with the other post, so in you last case you have $m=3$ and $n=1$ so the criterion is met.)

Comment: I found this post today by chance and it reminds me of a generalisation which I had asked some years ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2483738/72031

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EDIT: The classical demonstration of this is obtained by expanding in Fourier series the function $\cos(zx)$ with $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Let's detail Smirnov's proof (in "Course of Higher Mathematics 2 VI.1 Fourier series") :

$\cos(zx)$ is an even function of $x$ so that the $\sin(kx)$ terms disappear and the Fourier expansion is given by :
$$\cos(zx)=\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k\cdot \cos(kx),\ \text{with}\ \ a_k=\frac2{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cos(zx)\cos(kx) dx$$

Integration is easy and $a_0=\frac2{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(zx) dx= \frac{2\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}$ while
$a_k= \frac2{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(zx) \cos(kx) dx=\frac1{\pi}\left[\frac{\sin((z+k)x)}{z+k}+\frac{\sin((z-k)x)}{z-k}\right]_0^{\pi}=(-1)^k\frac{2z\sin(\pi z)}{\pi(z^2-k^2)}$
so that for $-\pi \le x \le \pi$ :

$$
\cos(zx)=\frac{2z\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\left[\frac1{2z^2}+\frac{\cos(1x)}{1^2-z^2}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2^2-z^2}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{3^2-z^2}-\cdots\right]
$$

Setting $x=0$ returns your equality :
$$
\frac1{\sin(\pi z)}=\frac{2z}{\pi}\left[\frac1{2z^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2-z^2}\right]
$$

while $x=\pi$ returns the $\mathrm{cotg}$ formula :

$$
\cot(\pi z)=\frac1{\pi}\left[\frac1{z}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2z}{k^2-z^2}\right]
$$
(Euler used this one to find closed forms of $\zeta(2n)$)

The $\cot\ $ formula is linked to $\Psi$ via the [Reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) :
$$\Psi(1-x)-\Psi(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)$$

The $\sin$ formula is linked to $\Gamma$ via [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) :
$$\Gamma(1-x)\cdot\Gamma(x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$$

Comment: Very nice. Guess I'll have to study Fourier series... What is the convergence domain of the given series? Do you have a link to Smirnov's book?

Comment: check my solution with $\psi(x)$, that's what I wanted!

Comment: @Peter: Nice! So we just had to observe (:-)) that $\tan(\frac a2)+\cot(\frac a2)= \frac 2{\sin(a)}\ $ and use the Reflection formula twice!

Comment: Can you tell me what is the domain of convergence of the series you found by Fourier analysis?

Comment: @Peter: I think that the formula is valid for any $z\ $ not in $\mathbb{Z}\ $ but please don't ask me for a rigorous proof! To get a reasonable approximation of the left term taking the sum for $k\ $ from $1$ to a little more than $|z|\ $ should be enough. For $z\in \mathbb{Z}\ $ only one term will remain!

Answer (score 19):

This is a very elegant and quick way to evaluate this sum with complex analysis. Consider

$$g(z) = \pi \csc (\pi z)f(z)$$

$\csc$ has poles at $2 \pi n$ and $2 \pi n + \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.  Assuming $f(z)$ has no poles at any  integer, the residue of $g(z)$ at $2n$ is

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z = 2 n} g(z) = \lim_{z\to 2 n}(z-2 n)\pi \csc (\pi z)f(z) = \lim_{z\to 2 n}\pi \left(\frac{z-2 n}{\sin (\pi z)}\right)f(z) = f(n)$$

and at $2n+1$:

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z = 2  n + 1} g(z) = \lim_{z\to 2  n + 1}(z-(2 n + 1))\pi \csc (\pi z)f(z) = \lim_{z\to 2 n + 1}\pi \left(\frac{z-2 n - 1}{\sin (\pi z)}\right)f(z) = -f(n)$$

Let $C_N$ be the square contour with the verticies $\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)(1+i)$, $\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)(-1+i)$, $\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)(-1-i)$ and $\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)(1-i)$.

By residue theorem, we have

$$\int_{C_N}g(z)\,dz = \sum_{n=-N}^N (-1)^n f(n) + S$$

where $S$ is the sum of the residues of the poles of $f$. Now, seeing that  the left side vanishes as $N \to \infty$ (see [here](http://www.duke.edu/%7Ead159/files/m185/23.pdf)), we have

---

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k f(k)=-\sum \text{Residues of }\pi \csc (\pi z)f(z)$$

Clearly the only singularity of $f(z)=\frac{1}{a+z}$ is at $z_0=-a$.  Thus

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_0} \,(\pi \csc (\pi z)f(z))=\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)\pi \csc (\pi z)f(z)=\lim_{z \to -a} \pi \csc (\pi z)\frac{z+a}{z+a}=-\pi \csc (\pi a)$$

Thus

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k f(k)=-\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_0}\,(\pi \csc (\pi z)f(z))=-(-\pi \csc (\pi a))=\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi a)}$$

QED

Comment: To be fair, the main computation is showing that $$\oint_{C_N} g(z) \, {\rm d}z =0 \, ,$$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$. Took me almost 2 pages.

Answer (score 10):

A related identity is proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) using residue theory. Here is a real approach to that identity.

---

**Convergence of the Principal Value**

We will look at the principal value
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{k+x}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac1x-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2x}{k^2-x^2}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(1b)}$ converges for all non-integer $x$.

---

**Properties of $\boldsymbol{f(x)}$**

$\bullet$ $f(x)$ has period $1$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)-f(x+1)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{k+x}-\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{k+1+x}\right)\tag{2a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{k+x}-\sum_{k=-n+1}^{n+1}\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag{2b}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{-n+x}-\frac1{n+1+x}\right)\tag{2c}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ definition
$\text{(2b):}$ substitute $k\mapsto k-1$ in the right sum
$\text{(2c):}$  the sums telescope
$\text{(2d):}$  evaluate the limit

$\bullet$ $f(1/2)=0$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(1/2)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{k+1/2}\tag{3a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1/2}\tag{3b}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ definition
$\text{(3b):}$ for $1\le j\le n$, the term with $k=j-1$ cancels the term with $k=-j$
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ which leaves the term with $k=n$
$\text{(3c):}$ evaluate the limit

$\bullet$ $f(x)^2+\pi^2=-f'(x)$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)^2
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{k+x}\sum_{j=-n}^n\frac1{j+x}\tag{4a}\\[3pt]
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(k+x)^2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{|j|,|k|\le n\\j\ne k}}\left(\frac1{k+x}-\frac1{j+x}\right)\frac1{j-k}\tag{4b}\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(k+x)^2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{|j|,|k|\le n\\j\ne k}}\frac2{k+x}\frac1{j-k}\tag{4c}\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(k+x)^2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\substack{|j|\le n\\j\ne k}}\left(\frac2{k+x}+\frac2{k-x}\right)\frac1{j-k}\tag{4d}\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(k+x)^2}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac2{k+x}+\frac2{k-x}\right)(H_{n+k}-H_{n-k})\tag{4e}\\
&=-f'(x)-4\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{4f}\\[12pt]
&=-f'(x)-\pi^2\tag{4g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ product of limits equals the limit of the products
$\text{(4b):}$ the left sum contains the terms with $j=k$
$\phantom{\text{(11):}}$ apply partial fractions to the right sum
$\text{(4c):}$ take advantage of the symmetry in $j$ and $k$
$\text{(4d):}$ for $k=0$, the sum in $j$ is $0$
$\phantom{\text{(4d):}}$ for $k\lt0$, if we substitute $(j,k)\mapsto(-j,-k)$,
$\phantom{\text{(4d):}}$ we get the sum with $k\gt0$ and $k+x\mapsto k-x$
$\text{(4e):}$ the sum in $j$ telescopes to $H_{n-k}-H_{n+k}$
$\text{(4f):}$ the left sum is $f'(x)$
$\phantom{\text{(4f):}}$ the right sum is a Riemann Sum with $\frac kn\mapsto t$ and $\frac1n\mapsto\mathrm{d}t$
$\phantom{\text{(4f):}}$ $H_{n+k}-H_{n-k}\mapsto\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)$ and $\frac2{k-x}+\frac2{k+x}\mapsto\frac{4\,\mathrm{d}t}t$
$\text{(4g):}$ $4\int_0^1\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2\,x^{2k}}{2k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=4\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{(2k+1)^2}=\pi^2$

---

**Conclude that $\boldsymbol{f(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)}$**

We can separate $(4)$ and integrate:
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\pi\,\mathrm{d}f}{f^2+\pi^2}&=-\int\pi\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
\tan^{-1}(f/\pi)&=C-\pi x\tag{5b}\\[9pt]
f&=\pi\tan(C-\pi x)\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
$(3)$ allows us to compute $C=\pi/2$, giving
$$
f(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)\tag6
$$
for $x\in(0,1)$. $(2)$ removes this restriction on $x$, validating $(6)$ for all non-integer $x$. That is,
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{k+x}=\pi\cot(\pi x)\tag7
$$
when taken in the principal value sense.

---

**Answer to the Question**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac2{2k+x}-\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{k+x}\tag{8a}\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{k+x/2}-\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{k+x}\tag{8b}\\[6pt]
&=\pi\cot(\pi x/2)-\pi\cot(\pi x)\tag{8c}\\[15pt]
&=\pi\csc(\pi x)\tag{8d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(8a):}$ the alternating sum is twice the sum of the even terms
$\phantom{\text{(8a):}}$ minus the sum of all the terms
$\text{(8b):}$ adjust the terms of the left sum to apply $(7)$
$\text{(8c):}$ apply $(7)$
$\text{(8d):}$ $\frac{1+\cos(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}-\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}=\frac1{\sin(\pi x)}$

Comment: $\text{(4g)}$ references $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}8$. A real derivation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703454).

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=0$ in the Fourier series of $\cos(ax)$:

$$\cos(ax)=\frac{2a\sin(\pi a)}{\pi}\left[\frac1{2a^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k\cos(kx)}{a^2-k^2}\right],\quad a\notin\mathbb{Z}$$

we get

\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi a)}&=\frac1a+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2a(-1)^k}{a^2-k^2}\\
&=\frac1a+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{a-k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{a+k}\\
&=\frac1a+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{a+k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{a+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{a+k}
\end{align}

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer by Raymond Manzoni?

Comment: @Gary First thanks for the downvote. Second I don't care if its different or not from other solutions, I just solve it my way. Third I see my solution well explained giving the desired result.

Comment: Imagine a hundred other people thought the same way and so we would have the same solution posted a hundred times. Would that make any sense?

Comment: @Gary its very rare to have many people to think the same way. we are created to be different in almost every little thing

Comment: $+1$ Nice.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @AliShadhar, I agree with you +1.