# Prove $\sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t+n)^2} = \frac{\pi^2 }{\sin^2(\pi t)}$ using $f(x)=\max (1-|x|,0)$ and Poisson summation formula

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'd like to prove

$$\sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t+n)^2} = \frac{\pi^2 }{\sin^2(\pi t)}$$

by using the Poisson summation formula. There is a way to do it by firstly taking the Fourier transform of $f(x) = 1 - |x|$ for $|x|\le1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $|x|>1$. There's a next step which I can't work out, and then you apply the Poisson summation formula.

I get the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ as $\frac{2(1-\cos y)}{y^2}$ but can't work out the next step so I can apply Poisson summation formula.

There's also a comment in a previous post back in April by user Lost about having done it. But I can't find any tips. I know it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Howdy! Welcome to MSE! In order for the latex/mathjax to be rendered properly you need to wrap it in `$` and `$$` if you want inline latex or not-inline latex respectively

Comment: Thanks for fixing it I was just in the process of looking it up :)

Comment: Related: [Showing $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121075/) & [$\sum\limits_{k = - \infty }^\infty {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}} = \frac{\pi }{{\sin \pi a}}} $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/110494/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an almost identical post:

[$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327392/sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n-alpha2-frac-pi2-sin-pi-alpha?rq=1)

I think there is a proof for this formula in Ahlfors independent of Possion summation formula(page 189 or 188) using elementary methods, which you can look up.

---

Here is a computational proof. We let
$$
f(x)=1-|x|, |x|\le 1; f(x)=0, |x|>1
$$
as you defined. It is easy to calculate the Fourier transform is given by
$$
\tilde{f}(\xi)=(\frac{\sin[\pi \xi]}{\pi \xi})^{2}
$$

I will leave the details to you. Then by summation formula we have
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x+n)=\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}\tilde{f}(n)e^{2\pi inx}
$$
We want to apply the formula using the fact that $f$ is $\tilde{f}$'s own Fourier transform. This holds since $f$ is in Schwarz class. Then we have
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}(\frac{\sin[\pi(x+n)]}{\pi (x+n)})^{2}=\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(n)e^{2\pi in x}
$$
We know that $\sin[\pi x+n\pi]^{2}=\sin[\pi x]^{2}$, therefore the left hand side can be factorized as
$$
\frac{\sin[\pi x]^{2}}{\pi^{2}}*\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)^{2}}
$$
While the right hand side is $f(0)=1$, because all other values simply vanish. Therefore we have
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{\sin[\pi x]^{2}}
$$ 
as desired.

Comment: I don't think this other solution addresses this problem using f(x) = 1- |x| etc and then using Poisson summation, which is how I'd like to solve it.

Comment: I think you should abandon your approach if it does not work out, or you can work out yourself instead.

Comment: I've reworded the question and added more information. I don't understand why it is suggested I should abandon it or do it myself, isn't this a forum for working things out.

Comment: For your courtesy I included a proof. I hope you can do this yourself next time.

Comment: Why is it that $f=\hat{f}$? I thought this applied strictly to the Gaussian, $e^{-\pi x^2}$.

Comment: @Bombyxmori since $f$ is in $L^1$ but not Schwartz class $\mathcal S$, we can only claim that Poisson summation formula is valid $a.e.$ instead of everywhere. I think you need to prove that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+n)$ is continuous to claim that poisson summation formula is valid in this case.