# Prove that $\sum_{n=-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{1}{(n+\alpha )^{2}}=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{(\sin\pi \alpha )^{2}}$ with poisson summation formula

Tags: real-analysis, summation, fourier-analysis, poisson-summation-formula

I want to show that $\sum_{n=-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{1}{(n+\alpha )^{2}}=\frac{\pi ^{2}}{(\sin\pi \alpha )^{2}}$, the introduction to the Poisson summation formula is in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula, I want to show this by using Poisson summation formula, the hint of this exercise says we can check the function $g$ such that $g=1-|x|$when $|x|\leq 1$ and $g=0$ otherwise, the Fourier transform of g is $F(g)(\xi)=(\frac{\sin(\pi \xi)}{\pi \xi })^{2}$, so how to use g and Poisson summation formula to prove it ? Can anyone help me, thank you in advance

Comment: I have written the names with capitals: Poisson, Fourier...

Comment: I have corrected it @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: please undo the downvote

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried? What hard moments did you encounter?

Comment: See this answer by Mhenni Benghorbal: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/208407

Comment: This has already been asked plenty of times, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327392/sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n-alpha2-frac-pi2-sin-pi-alpha?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810947/prove-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1tn2-frac-pi2-sin2-pi-t?rq=1)

Comment: The coments are misleading, the OP wants to use the Fourier transform of $\sin^2 x /x^2$ not $1/(x+a)^2$

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $$\sum_{n=-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{\sin^2(\pi (n+\alpha))}{\pi^2(n+\alpha )^{2}}=1=\sum_k e^{2i\pi \alpha k}g(k)$$