# How do I compute the characteristic function of the random variable with distribution function $F_X(x)=e^x/(1+e^x)$?

Tags: calculus, probability

I have computed the density function from the distribution function and used the definition of characteristic functions. I am stuck at the following integral.$$\varphi_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{(1+it)x}}{(1+e^x)^2} dx$$

I am given the following two hints:

1. $B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ for $\text{Re}(x)>0$ and $\text{Re}(y)>0$.
2. $\sin(\pi z)=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

A hint on how to proceed with this integral would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The usual step in this case is a substitution such as $u=e^x$ or $y=e^{-x}$

Comment: Note the density is an even function, so the characteristic function will also be even.

Comment: Contour integration seems like something that would work. Use a rectangular contour. It should come out to be $\pi t \operatorname{csch}(\pi t)$

Comment: Wait ah, you're doing it the beta function way. Nevermind then the contour integration. Use substitutions to convert your integral into the beta function form, split the beta into gammas, and then apply reflection.

Comment: @CaptainChicky Apologies for this is probably elementary, but I’m not sure how to use substitutions to obtain the form needed for the first hint.

Comment: You may try contour integration and calculus of residues.

Comment: @Mittens I believe this integral should be solved without having recourse to contour integration (just using the two provided hints and standard calculus).

Comment: I'll take a look with the beta method and write an answer hmm

Comment: @CaptainChicky Thank you!

Comment: @Leon: the identity (2) is not standard Calculus (unless you studied at Moscow State University) as it requires some Complex Analysis.  In any event, there are many ways to get. the integral.

Comment: this got closed after I edited my answer kekw rip average MSE experience ig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

You can try contour integration, in which you would closely follow the steps for a rectangular contour detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643287/int-infty-infty-fraceax1exdx-with-residue-calculus), but with higher order poles.

Or, the beta function method you have been hinted for. To do that, let me first establish $a=1+it$ because it's easier to write. The integral becomes
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{(1+e^x)^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{x}\right)^a}{(1+e^x)^2} dx$$
Enforce the substitution $$u=e^x$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=e^x,\quad \frac{dx}{du}=\frac1{e^x},\quad dx=\frac{du}{e^x}=\frac{du}{u}$$
The bounds transform as follows. Lower one is $e^{-\infty}=0$, and upper one is $e^\infty=\infty$.
(More formally, the differential manipulation can be justified with nonstandard analysis and the directly plugging in infinity should instead be done with a limit, but you get what I mean since this is pretty standard substitution i hope?)

Using this substitution yields
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{u^a}{(1+u)^2}\cdot\frac{du}{u} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{a-1}}{(1+u)^2} du = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{(1+it)-1}}{(1+u)^2} du$$

Since the beta function is given as $$\operatorname{B}(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
we have $$x = 1+it,\quad y=1-it$$

Our integral now becomes $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{(1+it)-1}}{(1+u)^{(1+it)+(1-it)}} du = \text{B}(1+it, 1-it) = \frac{\Gamma(1+it)\,\Gamma(1-it)}{\Gamma(2)}$$

This is just $$\Gamma(1+it)\,\Gamma(1-it)$$

I believe you can take it here on your own. Additional hints below ig.

> Use the property that $\Gamma(1+x) = x\,\Gamma(x)$.

> Apply it on $\Gamma(1+it)$ and then use your second hint, which is Euler's Reflection Formula. Manipulate it and solve for the Gamma duo, then plug your result in. It should simplify down to a hyperbolic function (this way you get rid of imaginary numbers).

Comment: Very helpful—thank you!

Comment: Could it be that the numerator after the substitution is $u^a$ and not $u^{a-1}$? The terms for the Beta function are then $x=2+it$ and $y=-it$. Using the properties of the Gamma function and the second hint I obtain $\varphi_X(t)=-i\pi(1+it)\sinh(\pi t)$.

Comment: @Leon the numerator has a -1 because of the differential. The substitution $u=e^x$ implies that $dx=du/e^x=du/u$. I just combined this $1/u$ with the top power. So after the substitution, the numerator is indeed $u^a$. Combine this with the differential’s scaling after the substitution and you get $u^{a-1}$

Comment: @Leon I've edited my answer to demonstrate that clearly

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out, much appreciated :-)