# Sum of infinite series with arctan: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{4}-n\right)-\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{4}-n\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the value of the following sum (if exist):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{4}-n\right)-\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{4}-n\right)\right)$$
where, $\arctan$ represent the inverse tangent function - $\tan^{-1}$.

I tried to use the telescoping series idea and the sequence of partial sums but I couldn't cancel any terms!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Maple, the value is approximately $0.54228694083149264109$.  Maple doesn't come up with a closed form, and neither its "identify" function nor the Inverse Symbolic Calculator  come up with anything.  Do you have any reason to believe there is a closed form for this number?

Comment: No, I have no idea if it has a closed form or not, or even if the sries converge! But if your answer is correct, that's good. If so, is the answer in radian? I mean, is it like $0.54228694083149264109 =0.003012705226841626 \pi$?

Comment: Cole, yes it is in radians, and you should not multiply it by $\pi/180$.   Your equation is false.  It is much closer to $0.1726\pi$, if you want to write it as something times $\pi$.

Comment: In fact a closed form solution may be found with some work (c.f. my answer). Perhaps that a more direct solution exists...

Answer (score 16):

Consider
$$\tag{1}f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\left(\frac 14-n\right)x\right)-\arctan\left(\left(-\frac 14-n\right)x\right)$$
and let's rewrite the derivative of $f$ :
\begin{align}
\tag{2}f'(x)&=\frac 4{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-4n}{(4n-1)^2+\bigl(\frac 4x\bigr)^2}-\frac{-1-4n}{(4n+1)^2+\bigl(\frac 4x\bigr)^2}\\
\tag{3}f'(x)&=\frac 4{x^2}\left(\frac {-1}{1^2+\left(\frac 4x\right)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k\sin\bigl(k\frac {\pi}2\bigr)}{k^2+\bigl(\frac 4x\bigr)^2}\right)\\
\end{align}
(since the $k=1$ term didn't appear in $(2)$)

But the series in $(3)$ may be obtained from $\,\frac d{d\theta} C_a(\theta)\,$ with :
$$\tag{4}C_a(\theta)=\frac {\pi}{2a}\frac{\cosh((\pi-|\theta|)a)}{\sinh(\pi a)}-\frac 1{2a^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(k\,\theta)}{k^2+a^2}$$
which may be obtained from the $\cos(zx)$ formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495) (with substitutions $\ x\to\pi-\theta,\ z\to ia$).

The replacement of the series in $(3)$ by $\,\frac d{d\theta} C_a(\theta)\,$ applied at $\,\theta=\frac {\pi}2$ gives us :
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\left(-\arctan\left(\frac x4\right)\right)'-\frac 4{x^2}C_{\frac 4x}\left(\theta\right)'_{\theta=\frac {\pi}2}\\
&=\left(-\arctan\left(\frac x4\right)\right)'+\frac{4\pi}{2x^2}\frac{\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}2 \frac 4x\right)}{\sinh\left(\pi\frac 4x\right)}\\
&=\left(-\arctan\left(\frac x4\right)\right)'+\frac{\pi}{x^2}\frac 1{\cosh\left(\frac{2\pi}x\right)}\\
\end{align}

Integrating both terms returns (with constant of integration $\frac {\pi}2$ since $f(0)=0$) :
$$f(x)=\frac {\pi}2-\arctan\left(\frac x4\right)-\arctan\left(\tanh\left(\frac {\pi}x\right)\right)\quad\text{for}\ \ x>0$$
i.e. the neat :
$$\tag{5}\boxed{\displaystyle f(x)=\arctan\left(\frac 4x\right)-\arctan\left(\tanh\left(\frac {\pi}x\right)\right)}\quad\text{for}\ \ x>0$$

So that your solution will be (for $x=1$) :
$$\boxed{\displaystyle \arctan(4)-\arctan\left(\tanh(\pi)\right)}$$

Comment: Nicer and simpler derivations are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638293/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-left-arctan-frac4n-12-arctan-frac4n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064218/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-left-frac18n2-right).

Answer (score 3):

**Only for the convergence:**
For every $n \ge 1$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n:&=&\arctan\left(\frac14-n\right)-\arctan\left(-\frac14-n\right)\\
&=&\arctan\left(n+\frac14\right)-\arctan\left(n-\frac14\right)\\
&=&\int_{n-\frac14}^{n+\frac14}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2(1+x_n^2)},
\end{eqnarray}
with
$$
x_n \in \left[n-\frac14,n+\frac14\right] \quad \quad \forall n \ge 1.
$$
Therefore
$$\tag{1}
f(n)\le a_n \le f(-n) \quad \forall n \ge 1,
$$
where
$$\tag{2}
f(z)=\frac{1}{2\left[1+(z+1/4)^2\right]}.
$$
It then follows from (1) that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, and 
$$
S_1:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le S_2:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(-n).
$$