# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \arctan \frac{4n - 1}{2} - \arctan \frac{4n - 3}{2} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I got stuck on the following series:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \arctan \frac{4n - 1}{2} - \arctan \frac{4n - 3}{2} \right). $$
I can't seem to make an approach because there's $-3$ not $+3$. Please help!

Comment: Yes (+1) Alternating series, but is it convergent???? What happens if n goes to infinity?

Comment: **No**, you are **not allowed** to get rid of those braces in this case! The conversion done by @CameronWilliams is **wrong**

Comment: @CameronWilliams It has nothing to do with absolute convergence. In general you are **allowed to set** braces whereever you want, **but not to remove them**. Second thing is allowed only if the resulting list is convergent as well, which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: It looks like the sum is $\tan^{-1}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613670/prove-this-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-left-dfrac1n21-right-arctan-l) might be relevant (in the sense of "method" rather than "full solution") since we have the identity $\arctan (a)-\arctan(b)=\arctan(\frac{a-b}{1-ab})$

Comment: If this series is indeed convergent, then changing the two arctan terms into one for sure can't be right, because then it would be divergent by alt series test. I need to ponder about this one.....

Comment: @user127001 So is the reason why you are not allowed to do what Cameron did, because the resulting alternating series is conditionally convergent? Meaning that a divergent series can be "re-arranged" into a convergent series and vice versa? Just asking here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the $n^{th}$ term of the series at hand. We have
$$\begin{align}
a_n = & \tan^{-1}\frac{4n-1}{2} - \tan^{-1}\frac{4n-3}{2}\\
= & \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{4n-1}{2}-\frac{4n-3}{2}}{1 + \frac{4n-1}{2}\frac{4n-3}{2}}\right)
= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2 + \frac34}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Notice $\;\tan^{-1}(x) = \Im\log(1 + ix)\;$ for real $x$, we can rewrite $a_n$ as

$$a_n = \Im\left\{\log\left( 1 + \frac{i}{(2n-1)^2 + \frac34}\right)\right\}
= \Im\left\{\log\left( 1 + \frac{\frac34 + i}{(2n-1)^2}\right)\right\}
$$

Compare this with the factors in the 
[infinite product expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html)
of $\cosh x$:

$$\cosh x = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 + \frac{4x^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right)$$
We find$\color{blue}{^{[1]}}$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 
= &\Im\left\{\log\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac34+i}\right)\right\}
= \Im\left\{\log\cosh\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1 + \frac{i}{2}\right)\right]\right\}\\
= & \Im\left\{\log\left[\cosh\frac{\pi}{2} \cos\frac{\pi}{4} + \sinh\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{4}i\right]\right\}
= \Im\left\{\log\left[ 1 + \tanh\frac{\pi}{2} i\right]\right\}\\
= & \tan^{-1}\left[\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]
\end{align}$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ Given any two complex numbers $u$ and $v$, $\log(uv)$ need not equal to $\log u + \log u$ in general. Instead, we have
  $$\log(uv) = \log u + \log v + i2\pi N$$
  for some integer $N$. So in principle,
  $$\begin{align}
  a_n &= \Im\left\{\log\left( 1 + \frac{\frac34 + i}{(2n-1)^2}\right)\right\}\\
  \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
  &= \Im\left\{\log\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left( 1 + \frac{\frac34 + i}{(2n-1)^2}\right)\right\}
  + 2\pi N
  \end{align}$$
  for some integer $N$ only. However, $a_n$ is small enough and the sum falls within the range $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, the $N$ here is actually zero. The naive looking replacement:
  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \quad\longrightarrow\quad
  \Im\left\{\log\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac34+i}\right)\right\}$$
  does work.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
     \arctan\pars{4n - 1 \over 2} - \arctan\pars{4n - 3 \over 2}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> \arctan\pars{4n - 1 \over 2} - \arctan\pars{4n - 3 \over 2}}}
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
> \int_{\pars{4n + 1}/2}^{\pars{4n + 3}/2}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{x \equiv {4n + 1 \over 2} + \xi}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\arctan\pars{4n - 1 \over 2} - \arctan\pars{4n - 3 \over 2}}}
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd\xi \over \bracks{\pars{4n + 1}/2 + \xi}^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{2n + 1/2 + \xi + \ic}\pars{2n + 1/2 + \xi - \ic}}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{n + 1/4 + \xi/2 + \ic/2}\pars{n + 1/4 + \xi/2 - \ic/2}}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}
{\Psi\pars{1/4 + \xi/2 + \ic/2} - \Psi\pars{1/4 + \xi/2 - \ic/2} \over \ic}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] = &\
\half\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}\Psi\pars{1/4 + \xi/2 + \ic/2}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{3/4 + \ic/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1/4 + \ic/2}} =
\Im\ln\pars{%
\Gamma\pars{{3 \over 4} + {\ic \over 2}}\Gamma\pars{{1 \over 4} - {\ic \over 2}}}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\pars{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\ln\pars{\pi\root{2} \over \cosh\pars{\pi/2} - \ic\sinh\pars{\pi/2}} =
\arctan\pars{\tanh\pars{\pi \over 2}}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\pars{2}
\end{align}

---

In $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$ we used identity ${\bf\mbox{6.1.32}}$ of
[$\large\mbox{this table}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm).
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{%
\arctan\pars{4n - 1 \over 2} - \arctan\pars{4n - 3 \over 2}}}
\\[5mm]  = &\
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{\arctan\pars{\tanh\pars{\pi \over 2}}} \approx 0.7422
\end{align}