# Evaluate the Series in Closed Form: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Please help me find in closed form a value for

$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2}    
$$

Bearing in mind there is no "$x$" term, I would assume the solution involves instituting some form of $x^n$ and letting $S=f(1)$.  I've tried doing so, along with taking derivatives of the function, hoping to somehow turn the series into a DE, so that the original function can be obtained.  I've worked on it for hours, I'm baffled.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a reason to think that this series has a closed form expression?

Comment: This may be done with Fourier series as proposed by muzzlator as shown in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495) (or with residus as shown by Argon). See $\frac 1{\sin(\pi z)}$ where you'll have to replace $z$ by $ia$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Series like these may be evaluated by the Residue Theorem:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n) = -\sum_k \text{Res}_{z=z_k}[ \pi \csc{(\pi z)} f(z)]$$

where the $z_k$ are poles of $f$ away from the real line.

In your case

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+a^2}$$

The poles of $f$ are at $z_{\pm} = \pm i a$.  Then the sum on the right is

$$-\pi \left( \frac{-i\, \text{csch}{(\pi a)}}{i 2 a} + \frac{i\, \text{csch}{(\pi a)}}{-i 2 a}\right ) $$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2} = \frac{\pi}{a} \text{csch}{(\pi a)}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\pi}{a} \text{csch}{(\pi a)} + \frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$

Comment: That's really cool.  I had heard of residue theory being used to calculate sums before but I have never seen it actually done

Comment: @muzzlator: in cases like this, it is very simple to apply.

Comment: Thank you much.  You can't imagine the frustration I've had this past 12 hours.  I would have never guessed... 

Thanks again!

Comment: @Gerg: I am glad this helped you, and I hope you got the point for future, similar problems.  Please remember to accept the solution you like best.

Comment: @RonGordon I don't know the residue theorem in this form, do you have a reference to this result please?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: see this for example: http://www.math.odu.edu/~jhh/ch95.PDF.  There are more, and better, but this one was immediately available.

Comment: @RonGordon Very interesting paper, thank you very much.