# Find $\sum _{ n=-\infty }^{ \infty }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( j\omega +j\frac { 2\pi n }{ T } \right) }^{ 2 } } }$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( j\omega +j\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }$$

final answer is
$$-\frac { { T }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ 1-cos(\omega T) }  \right)$$

Where$$ j=\sqrt { -1 }$$

I tried to take out $j$ which gives me negative sign and then I tried to solve the parentheses but things are getting complicated. Is there any mathematical trick to get the final answer as shown?

Comment: You should have used $i=\sqrt{-1}$ which I think is a more common form of "iota" and you may not need to explicitly state , then, $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: Especially since, after getting rid of $i^2$ and replacing $\omega$ by $\omega T$, the question reduces to show that, for every real number $\omega$ not a multiple of $2\pi$, $$\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^\infty\frac1{\left(\omega +2\pi n\right)^2}=  \frac1{1-\cos\omega}.$$ And this notationally simpler version could ring a bell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( j\omega +j\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }=\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { j^2\left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }=-\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }=$$

$$-\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }=\frac{d}{d\omega } (\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  } }  })$$

now we need to find out

$$\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  } }  }$$

There is a series representation as partial fraction expansion where just translated reciprocal functions are summed up, such that the poles of the cotangent function and the reciprocal functions match. [Reference link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)
Please check note 12.

$$\pi \cot(\pi x)=\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( x+n \right)  } }  }$$

There is also a proof in  [here](http://www-m9.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/WS2010/IMCSeminar/Cotangent.pdf) how to get that series expansion.

Now we can use this identity and get :

$$\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  } }  }=\frac { T  }{ 2\pi }\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \frac {\omega T }{ 2\pi   } +n \right)  } }  }=$$

$$=\pi . \frac { T  }{ 2\pi }\cot(\pi \frac {\omega T }{ 2\pi   })=\frac { T  }{ 2 }\cot(\frac {\omega T }{ 2   })$$

Now just you need to do final step.

$$\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( j\omega +j\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }=\frac{d}{d\omega } (\sum _{ n=-\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( \omega +\frac { 2\pi n }{ T }  \right)  } }  })=\frac{d}{d\omega }(\frac { T  }{ 2 }\cot(\frac {\omega T }{ 2   }))$$

Can you finalize it to get the answer that you wrote?
Please let me know if you need help.

EDIT: I also found a nice proof for series expansion of $ \cot(x)$ in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495). It was shared by @Raymond Manzoni

Comment: @Sheldon: For an alternative proof of the formula used here, see the answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470) question.