# Proving $\pi \coth \pi a= \frac{1}{a}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2a}{n^2+a^2}$ using the Fourier series for $\cosh ax$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

The exercise wants me to prove the identity

$$\pi \coth \pi a= \frac{1}{a}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2a}{n^2+a^2}$$

using the Fourier series of $\cosh ax, \; x \in [-\pi, \pi], \; a \neq 0$.

---

Evaluating the coefficients ($b_n$ is actually zero as $\cosh ax$ is even) we have that:

$\displaystyle {\color{gray} \blacksquare} \;\; a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cosh ax \, {\rm d}x= \frac{2\sinh \pi a}{\pi a}$

$\require{cancel}\displaystyle  {\color{gray} \blacksquare} \;\; a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cosh ax \cos n x\, {\rm d}x= \frac{2[a \sinh \pi a \cos \pi n+ \cancelto{0}{n \cosh \pi a \sin \pi n}]}{\pi (a^2+n^2)}$

So far so good except one little problem. I get that $\cos \pi n$ in the nominator which is $(-1)^n$ so I get the alternating series not the wanted one. That is , this way I evaluated the series:

$$\cosh ax = \frac{\sinh \pi a}{\pi a}+ \frac{2 a\sinh \pi a}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^n}{n^2 +a^2} \implies \\
\implies \pi\coth \pi a = \frac{1}{a}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^n}{n^2+a^2}$$

and not what I want. Calculations of the coefficients were done by Wolfram because they were too tedious to be done by hand.

However, I know that using contour integration using the kernel $\pi \cot \pi z$ that this series indeed evaluates to the LHS. What is wrong here?

Comment: Hint: variable $x$ does not appear in the RHS of your result, as it should.

Comment: Yes... but I cannot see where the mistake is. As for $x$ you are right. Then I plug in $x=\pi$.

Comment: Oups... I forgot the $\cos nx$ is the RHS.

Comment: Yes, and then you must put $x=\pi$.

Comment: Similar [work](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495) with $a:=iz$.

Comment: I didn't know about `\cancelto{}{}`, very cool!

Comment: @GFauxPas Yeah... but it does not work uless you call it. That you write the command \require{cancel} etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I forgot to add the $\cos nx$ in the RHS. Hence:

$$\cosh ax = \frac{\sinh \pi a}{\pi a}+ \frac{2 a\sinh \pi a}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^n \cos nx}{n^2 +a^2} \overset{x=\pi}{\implies}$$

$$\overset{x=\pi}{\implies} \pi \coth \pi a= \frac{1}{a}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2a}{n^2+a^2}$$

and the identity is proven.

@Aretino, thanks for the heads up.