# Find $\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin x}{x(1+\cos ^2 x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

find the value:
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin x}{x(1+\cos ^2 x)}dx$$
I try to integrate by parts:
$$-\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{x}d\arctan(\cos x)$$
But it's not run,help me,thank you.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154292/find-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxx-cos2-x-mathrmdx).

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
\begin{align}
I=&\ \int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin x}{2x(1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2x)}\ dx = \frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{\sin^{2k}x}{2^k}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{2^k}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\sin^{2k+1}x}{x}\ dx
\end{align}
If you believe that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\sin^{2k+1}x}{x}\ dx = \binom{2k}{k}\frac{\pi}{4^k}
\end{align}

then it follows that

\begin{align}
I=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{8^k} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}

Note that the last line follows from the series expansion
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^k}{4^k}.
\end{align}

Comment: This is very nice. However, I noted that this does not agree exactly with the numerical result given by WolframAlpha which is $1.12581$, whereas the number $\pi/(2\sqrt2)=1.1107...$

Comment: Could be just a small numerical error of WA. I tried also numerical integration with MATLAB and got a message that it does not converge. Indeed the integrand is an oscillating function.

Comment: @Jacky Chong thank you for your nice answer,great answer!

Answer (score 4):

It can be computed as a [Lobachevsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula)-type integral (see also [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776903) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2219101) here on MSE): $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x(1+\cos^2 x)}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2 x}\underset{\tan x=y}{\phantom{\big[}\quad=\quad\phantom{\big]}}\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{2+y^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: thank you very much,intristing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment

---

Introduce a parameter $a$:

$$\bbox[5px,#ffd]{I(a)=\int \frac{\sin ax}{x(1+\cos ^2 x)}dx}$$

$$I'(a)=\int \frac{\cos ax}{(1+\cos ^2 x)}dx$$

$$I''(a)=\int \frac{-x\sin ax}{(1+\cos ^2 x)}dx=-xI(a)+\int I(a)$$

$$I'''(a)=-xI'(a)+I(a)$$

The solution of this differential equation is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%3Dcy%27%2By).

Note that $c=-x,y=I(a)$ and $x=a$

Comment: How would you get an exact solution though, I believe your initial conditions would be hard to calculate or undefined...

Comment: @HenryLee we can obtain the solution by substituting $a=1$ in that huge expression and then applying the limits from $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: Would you at least check the *result*? (Not even talking about the *deduction*... Nonsense, beginning with $I''(a)=-xI(a)+\ldots$)

Comment: @metamorphy As I have stated before, I don't know how to solve that differential equation by hand. Wolframalpha did that, but it doesn't let me substitute the limits. So I leave it as it is.