# Find $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x+x\cos^2 x }\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have just done these, but I don't know what to do next......

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sin x}{x+x\cos^2 x}\,\mathrm{d}x & = \int \frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin  x}{1+\cos^2 x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int \frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}(\arctan(-\cos x))\\\
&=\frac{1}{x} \arctan(-\cos x)-\int -\frac{1}{x^2} \arctan(-\cos x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{1}{x} \arctan(-\cos x)-\int \frac{\arctan(\cos x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply [Lobachevsky's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula): if $f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ meets $f(\pi\pm x)=f(x)$, then $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx.$$ The given integral is then equal to $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2 x}\ \underset{t=\tan x}{\phantom{\big[}=\phantom{\big]}}\ \int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{2+t^2}=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity :  could you elaborate a bit starting from the integral  in title ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: Nice(+1) but I have a question : Does Lobachevsky's formula gives approximate results? Your answer seems to be $1.110720...$ but answer of the integral by Wolfram is $1.12581...$. I tried this on another problem and again seems to be approximate.

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh: It is exact (look for a proof). Wolfy doesn't handle integrals of this kind well.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: see the edit (just extracted the formula itself).

Comment: Proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776903).

Comment: thanks a lot !!!!