# Infinite sum of an alternating series in the topic of Fourier analysis.

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have been given the task of showing that $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2-\frac{1}{4}} = 2\pi$ and quite frankly I am stuck. So far I have shown that $|c_n|^2 = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^2-\frac{1}{4})^2} = 2\pi^2$ by using Parseval's Identity with the function $f(x) = |\cos(\frac{x}{2})|$. I hope someone here is able to help in advance thanks for your help.

Comment: This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left) may help (consider the Fourier series for $\,z:=\dfrac 12$).

Comment: Or you can apply the same method to $\sum_n \frac{1}{((2n)^2-1/4)^2}$ and subtract the two series