# Mittag–Leffler partial fraction decomposition for $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Question from the book Eberhard Freitag, Rolf Busam - Complex Analysis]

I marked my question in the image. My problem is that I don’t see that the two marked formula for the function $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ are different.

Comment: Where did the $(-1)^n/n$ part go?

Comment: What textbook is this from?

Answer (score 1):

The formulas given are
$$
h(z)=\frac1z+\sum_{n\ne0}\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{z-n}+\frac{(-1)^n}n\right]\tag1
$$
and
$$
h(z)=\frac1z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac1{z-n}+\frac1{z+n}\right]\tag2
$$
The standard convention is that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\tag3
$$
However, the less commonly known, but often used, convention is that for double-ended sums,
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^Na_n\tag4
$$
where we maintain the standard convergence requirement that $\lim\limits_{|n|\to\infty}|a_n|=0$. Sometimes, $(4)$ is called the Principal Value of the sum, which is the same as the convention.

Applying $(4)$ to $(1)$, we get that
$$
\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n}n=0\tag5
$$
in which case, both $(1)$ and $(2)$ agree.

Comment: This is perfect! My problem is that the book claims that formula (1) and formula (2) differs from each other by an intire function! I don't understand why, I think these formulas are the same, just like you wrote it.

Comment: $0$ is an entire function, but I myself have often used $$\pi\csc(\pi z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+z}$$ as well as $$\pi\cot(\pi z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+z}$$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077))

Comment: Ok, so you think that the book refers to the zero entire function in the yellowed marked sentence, don't you?

Comment: The difference comes out to $(5)$, so it seems it would be $0$.